# Forecasting using Multiple Regression in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, regression, forecasting

Pity Google BigQuery still doesn't have a function such as `forecast()` that we see in Spreadsheets-- don't look down on yet; given one has the statistical know-how, surprising amount of smoothing and seasonality can be added to forecasting on spreadsheets.

BigQuery allows you to determine Standard Deviation, correlation and intercept metrics. Using that, one can create the prediction model-- refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51768035/6532822) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462362/how-to-perform-linear-regression-in-bigquery?noredirect=1&lq=1). But that uses Linear regression model; so we are not happy with the seasonality aspect. Question is, how can we construct Multiple regression model for prediction in BigQuery?

If `Y = a1x1+a2x2+a3x3+c`, do we (1) separately determine a1, a2 and a3 and finally join the queries? But what about the intercept? How do we calculate one for MR in Bigquery?

Any contribution will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does BigQuery's new ML feature help you? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-intro

Comment: Bigquery ML uses Linear Regression in its training model. It may be efficient, but we are talking about MR here! Thanks!

Comment: Most likely they'll add more models in future, so worth keeping an eye on it.

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolly, thanks for commenting. About Google BQML, I have a question about applying a training model built on a table ('date', 'sales') on future dates. 

So, in the 'ML.PREDICT' query part, if I replace the 'date' field with UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('immediate future start date'),DATE('30-days-on-stop-date'))) --- will it work?

Comment: Did you try it? ;-)

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolly, it sort of works. But just extending the date may not be a correct method, considering the forecasting has only learnt past seasonalities and we have no way to put in the future influencers. Is there a way to input future influencers?