# Bigquery Standard SQL "max_by" and "regr_slope" functions

Tags: google-bigquery, gradient, maxby

Is there any equivalent function in Bigquery using Standard SQL for max_by and regr_slope functions. If not how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Maniyar

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that BigQuery supports either of these functions out of the box.  For `MAX_BY`, you may just use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
-- replacement for MAX_BY(col, val)
-- find the value for col which generates the MAX value

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Or, you could use `LIMIT` if your version of BigQuery supports that:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY val DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

As for doing linear regressions in BigQuery, I refer you to [this highly upvoted Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462362/how-to-perform-linear-regression-in-bigquery) question and answer.

Comment: The first query in the above example (ROW_NUMBER) requires a PARTITION BY clause. My further requirement is I need to join this query output to another result set. The size of the table is 100GB, will there be any problem in terms of performance and the resource limit

Comment: Well since BigQuery does not support indexing AFAIK, then yes, there may be a peformance penalty for such a large table.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. Is there any other alternate in my scenario

Comment: Note that I can readily think of.  If BigQuery supports triggers, you could try to implement a trigger which compares a new incoming value against the current max, and if larger, then writes that new max value to a second table.

Comment: Linear regression: BigQuery now can `CREATE MODEL`, and then predict with `SELECT FROM ML.PREDICT`. There's a better alternative to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`, which is `ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY y LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score 1):

As @felipe-hoffa commented in another question, the shortest way to replace `MAX_BY` seems to use `ARRAY_AGG` like this:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS max_x_by_y
FROM yadda_yadda
```

Comment: Do you not get the compliler complaining about correlated subqueries?